# Updating the state with nested Immutable records

Tags: reactjs, immutable.js

I have an Immutable.js record for an Editor, which has nested records for the content and selection.

So whenever the selection changes, I would get the start and end points of the selection, and then update the state with a new selection.

```
class SelectionStateRecord extends Immutable.Record({
        anchor: 0,
        focus: 0,
    }
) {
    // extra features
}

class EditorRecord extends Immutable.Record({
        key: uuid.v4(),
        ContentState: new ContentStateRecord(),
        SelectionState: new SelectionStateRecord(),
    }
) {
    // extra features
}

export default class TextEditor extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            EditorState: new EditorRecord()
            ...
        }
    }

    _onSelectionChange = e => {
        const {start, end} = e.nativeEvent.selection
        const newEditorState = this.state.EditorState.SelectionState.merge({
            focus: start,
            anchor: end,
        })
        this.setState({EditorState: newEditorState})
    }

    render() {
        ...
    }
}
```

But, I am getting this error, I am guessing I cannot just set a new value to a nested record:

> undefined is not an object (evaluating '_this.state.EditorState.SelectionState.merge')

However, this works:

```
    _onSelectionChange = e => {
        const {start, end} = e.nativeEvent.selection
        const newEditorState = this.state.EditorState.merge({
            key: uuid.v4(),
            ContentState: this.state.EditorState.ContentState,
            SelectionState: this.state.EditorState.SelectionState.merge({
                focus: start,
                anchor: end,
            }),
        })
        this.setState({EditorState: newEditorState}, () => {
            console.log('start', this.state.EditorState.SelectionState.start())
        })
    }
```

I am just not sure if this is the right way to update the state, and confused how to set/update values to a individual nested Immutable record as to avoid performance loss.

Answer (score 0):

Can you just use `updateIn()`? [docs](https://immutable-js.github.io/immutable-js/docs/#/Map/updateIn)

e.g.

```
_onSelectionChange = e => {
        const {start, end} = e.nativeEvent.selection
        const newEditorState = this.state
          .updateIn(
            ['EditorState', 'SelectionState'],
            new SelectionStateRecord(), // default value (optional)
            ss => ss.set('focus', start).set('anchor', end)
          )
        )

        this.setState({EditorState: newEditorState}, () => {
            console.log('start', this.state.EditorState.SelectionState.start())
        })
    }
```